# Swift : how to list fields in a struct from Type object?

Tags: swift, struct, introspection, mirror

I want to extract a list of the fields in a `struct`, having at my disposal just the `Type` object.

```swift
public struct CoordinateData: Codable {
  var longitude: Double?
  var latitude: Double?
}
```

I receive `Codable.Type` (at this stage, I do not know the object is `CoordinateData` and I want to keep my solution generic for any `Codable`)
I want to extract ["longitude", "latitude"] (`[String]`)

I tried to use `Mirror` and it works when I know the exact type of the object and when the type as an empty initializer:

```swift
let metatype: CoordinateData.Type = CoordinateData.self
let c3 = metatype.init()
let m3 = Mirror(reflecting: c3)
for (property, value) in m3.children {
    guard let property = property else {
        print("no proeprty")
        continue
    }
    print(property)
}
```

But this solution does not work when all I have is `Codable.Type` because it has only one `.init()` method that expect a decoder `.init(from: Decoder)` which I don't have.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Can you clarify this: are you trying to get a list of the names of the stored properties, or are you trying to get a list of the properties that will be encoded/decoded (i.e. coding keys)? These are not necessarily the same. If you mean the former, then the type being `Codable` is irrelevant. If you mean the latter, then its impossible, because what coding keys a `Codable` uses is essentially an implementation detail, and can change depending on the instance.

Comment: @Sweeper, for the latter it would be possible (and easier) to just create mock *`Encoder`/`Decoder` that would just dump keys instead of doing proper coding/decoding.

Comment: @user28434 What I meant was, the coding keys that a `Codable` uses is not inherent to the type of `Codable`. Heck, it's not even inherent to the instance. One could use a different type of `CodingKey` when encoding and decoding. Or, when decoding, one could generate a random number, and use different `CodingKey`s depending on that, or only decode a few of all the possible coding keys. Although this is not useful, there is no rule that says you can't do that...

Comment: @sweeper. I am trying to get the former : a [String] with the name

Comment: @user28434 : I thought about that. But implementing a full encoder or decoder seems like a **lot** of code.  before going into that possibility, I wanted to see if there is an easier way provided by introspection

Answer (score 3):

This could work, But you need to consider a few things.

```
func mirror<T: Any>(object: T) {
   let c3 = object
   let m3 = Mirror(reflecting: c3)
   for (property, _) in m3.children {
       guard let property = property else {
           print("no proeprty")
           continue
       }
        print(property)
      }
   }
```

Use: `mirror(object: CoordinateData())
     mirror(object: Foo())`

You always need to pass an initialized object.

That would remove the init responsibility from the function because as far as i know, you can't initialize the generic objects because they're generic.

So bypassing the object itself this would work for you.

Update: since there is no explicit struct type parameter this could be misused also but passing any argument that's not an object it wouldn't give any result, this could be solved by changing the structs to classes and pass `<T>` as `<T: AnyObject>`.

You can alternatively do it this way too, since `Mirror` parameter is already `Any` type, so we can extension the `Mirror` it self to make a `getProperties()` function check below.

```
 extension Mirror {
 func getProperties() -> [String] {
 self.children.compactMap { child in
 guard let property = child.label else {
 return nil
     }
 return property
    }
  }
 }
```

Usage: `var list = Mirror(reflecting: Foo()).getProperties()`
This will always give you an array of strings, however if there were no properties it would return an empty array.

Comment: It works even if `<T: Any>` replaced with just `<T>`. Or are there some caveats?

Comment: @user28434 since there is not explicit struct type parameter this could be misused also but passing any argument that's not an object it wouldn't give any result.

Comment: @SébastienStormacq  glad to help :)) happy coding.

Comment: Actually, after double check, no it does not work for me. Because I can not write `Mirror(reflecting: Foo())` I just receive a `Type` object of something that inherits `Codable`. So basically I have a `Codable.Type` and I can not write `foo.init()` when Foo is `Codable.Type`. `Codable.Type` has only `.init(from: Decodable)`

Comment: @SébastienStormacq even so I think you can `init()` what swift version are you using

Comment: Swift v5. "Missing argument for parameter 'from' in call" Codable has only one initializer :-(

Comment: @SébastienStormacq its because you have non-optional properties you can either make everything optional or we can try to work around it but not sure if possible

Comment: you can. also, send dummy data to the object try this make them non-optional `CoordinateData(longitude: 0, latitude: 0)` and try this way

Comment: the autocomplete wont give this sometimes :) Xcode things

Comment: I don't think I can resolve this generically.  Basically I would need to instantiate an object without knowing anything about required fields.  Another way to ask my original question : can we introspect the list of properties using **only** the Type object, not one of its instance ?

Comment: the thing is mirror works only with objects and not types somehow we need to pass that. 
if you check childrens they have `label` and `value` i don't know another way where it reflects a type

Comment: @SébastienStormacq i wonder what's the actual use case of this maybe we could work with something else.

Comment: Mirror is indeed limited to objects introspection. Not Type.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/mirror

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215569/discussion-between-mohmmad-s-and-sebastien-stormacq).